# dynamically render the array at different labels inside return function react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am trying to render the values from array at different places in return function in the page using below code

```
   return (
  <div style={{ margin: 30 }}>
    <div className="form-group form-inline">
      <label style={{ display: 'margin-right:10px' }}>
      Section:</label> {requestDatasource[0].section}
    </div>
    <div className="form-group form-inline">
      <label style={{ display: 'margin-right:10px' }}>Type: </label> {requestDatasource[0].type}
    </div>
    <div className="form-group form-inline">
      <label style={{ display: 'margin-right:10px' }}>
      Requested By :     
      </label> {requestDatasource[0].createdBy}
    </div>
   <div className="form-group form-inline">
      <label style={{ display: 'margin-right:10px' }}>Requested Date: </label>

      {requestDatasource[0].createat}

    </div>
  </div>
 );
```

and i am filling array with the values like this below

```
if (requestData != null) {
requestData.allRequests.map((code) => {
  requestDatasource.push({
    id: code.id,
    section: code.masterSection.name,
    createdBy: code.createdBy,
    type: code.requestType.name,
    status: code.requestStage.name,
    createat: new Date(code.createdAt),
  });
  return null;
});
}
```

but somehow i am getting this error

```
 `Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`
```

I am not sure where i am going wrong with this code, Could any one please let me know what will be the problem  with the above code in return method.

**PS: i am using react js functional components**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you print `requestDatasource` and add its output?

Comment: @AshutoshKS the problem lies here at `createat: new Date(code.createdAt)` is there any possible we can convert it into normal date

Comment: What's the value of `code.createdAt`? Is it a string or what (also what is it value)?

Comment: it is dateTime getting from the backend and the format is like this `2019-12-14T13:58:37.063-08:00`  and i wanted just date in the format `mm-dd-yyyy`

Comment: Are you sure `createat: new Date(code.createdAt)` is the problem? It's because `new Date("2019-12-14T13:58:37.063-08:00")` works perfectly, i.e., it's a correct variable of type `Date`.

Comment: the problem lies there if i remove new Date it is working with the date format that i mentioned before

Comment: Are you using `requestDatasource[0].createat` (the Date object)? If yes, could you paste the relevant code since I can't see it in the pasted JSX under `return()` in your question.

Comment: i updated my question and included createdat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under JSX, you must use primitive values and not objects like `Date`. So, modify your code:

```js
<div className="form-group form-inline">
  <label style={{ display: 'margin-right:10px' }}>Requested Date: </label>

  {requestDatasource[0].createat.toString()} /* or any other String() */

</div>
```

That's the reason that when you updated your code `createat: new Date(code.createdAt)` to `createat: code.createdAt`, then it worked since now `createat` was a string, which works in JSX.

You can also use other `Date.to***String()` methods like `toUTCString()` or `toLocaleString()`.

Comment: getting an error for `requestDatasource[0].createat.toUTCString is not a function`

Comment: It's `toLocaleString()`, check more `Date.to***String()` functions at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Does my exact code work? Or `toString()` is also not working?

Comment: toString () is working but i need the format like this `mm-dd-yyyy` format

Comment: It's hard to format `Date` in JavaScript without a library (like https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat). You can try `requestDatasource[0].createat.toLocaleString().substring(0, 10)`.

Comment: i am getting format like this`2019-12-14` but i am looking for this format `mm-dd-yyyy`

Comment: @EnigmaState This code works: `const d1 = new Date('December 16, 2019 03:24:00'); console.log((d1.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d1.getDate() + "-" + d1.getYear());`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the value of `requestDatasource[0].section`, `requestDatasource[0].type`, and/or `requestDatasource[0].createdBy` are Objects? I'd start of by double checking that the values are what you're expecting them to be.

---

Somewhat unrelated, but I think that you could use `map` in a better way, or change it to `forEach`. The way you're using it now is to say, "For each value in `requestData.allRequests`, push a new object to `requestDatasource`." And the fact that you're returning `null` is evidence that you don't need a `map`. If you change `map` to `forEach`, you can remove the `return null` and have an easy win.

That said, I think that your intuition to use `map` might be correct. And rather than `push` to an external `requestDatasource`, maybe you can generate your new data structure using the `map`, and create `requestDatasource` right there:

```js
const requestDatasource = requestData.allRequests.map(code => {
  return {
    id: code.id,
    section: code.masterSection.name,
    createdBy: code.createdBy,
    type: code.requestType.name,
    status: code.requestStage.name,
    createdAt: new Date(code.createdAt)
  };
});
```